# Does Canon 5D Mark III support 256GB MicroSD?

Tags: canon-5d-mark-iii, memory-card-size, microsd

I'm currently thinking about getting a 256GB MicroSD card to use with a Canon 5D Mark III DSLR camera, and am wondering what the maximum MicroSD card capacity is supported by the camera.

Does anyone know the largest MicroSD card capacity supported by the Canon 5D Mark III camera?

Comment: That ought to store in excess of 9000+ RAW format photos. The battery lasts for about 700+ shots. Are you carrying around 13 batteries? Just curious.

Comment: @Octopus Video?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MicroSD cards are supported provided you use them with an adapter.

The 5D Mk III manual says it can use cards over 128GB capacity so I would assume there is no upper limit.

[image]

Comment: There IS an upper limit given by the filesystem (exFAT) limitations. That limit, however is so high we can just ignore it, because there are no CF or SD cards that big: 2TB

Comment: @Dragos We can ignore it **for now**.  Probably not for all that long, though.

Comment: @Dragos [exFAT's volume size limit is approximately 128 PiB, with 512 TiB being the recommended maximum volume size.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#cite_ref-xpkb_1-0) Maybe you are thinking of FAT32, which does have a maximum volume size of 2 TB (when used with 512 byte sectors) and [was introduced in 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32)?

Answer (score 5):

The [Official Canon 5D Mark III website](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/cameras/dslr/eos-5d-mark-iii/!ut/p/z1/hY7LDoIwEEW_xQ8gUxGRLlsIoYZqYKG1G9MIYiOvFOLCr7caN8aIs7uZc28OSBAgW3XTlRp116ra5oP0jzxLgoSFKA2CnCLCIxTPM8_dpi7s_wHSvtGPIwjWL2Cibw1cw0NegezVeHF0e-5AnFRTGjWAKIbagCi7wVkWTqPM1dFaWyv5uYtyvELEj_wEbyhizPsCdtSzAI7ChRs_3d7AhHrfiHtKMdNkNnsAxqbKog!!/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) says:

> Recording Media
>
> CF Cards (Type I); Compatible with UDMA CF cards; SD, SDHC, and SDXC Memory Cards

Note: No microSD is supported unless you use a microSD-to-SD adapter.

It's also worthwhile to mention, a MicroSD-to-SD adapter would not bring any loss of performance (either in writing or reading speeds) since the adapter is doing nothing but connecting the pins of the MicroSD card to the contacts of the SD slot.

The maximum size of CF or SD cards supported, 128 GB, is certainly supported for both CF and SD Cards.

I haven't yet found any information regarding 256 GB cards being supported by this camera.

Later edit: I have found a review of the camera specifying that Canon declares 256 GB cards will work just fine with the camera. [Photo.net Review](http://photo.net/equipment/canon/5D-MkIII/preview/)

> The cards normally use the FAT32 file system but the 5D Mark III supports exFAT not only for SDXC but also for CF cards with storage capacities greater than 128GB. Maximum card size isn’t specified, but Canon commented that the latest 256GB cards work just fine and larger cards should work in the future. I can’t say for sure if the full 2TB limit of the file systems will be fully supported, but I think the day of 2TB cards is probably far enough away that it’s not really much of a concern (not to mention such cards would likely cost more than the camera…). UDMA mode 7 is supported.

Comment: Not sure why you say "no microSD supported". [The only difference is the physical size.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroSD#Physical_size) "**The SD card specification defines three physical sizes.** ... Smaller cards are usable in larger slots through use of **a passive adapter.**" (My emphasis.) No matter what the hardware, "passive adapter" implies at the very least protocol-level compatibility, and has a very high probability of also being electrically compatible (so the only difference is the size and location of the electrical contacts).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling exactly! the physical size of a microSD is not supported by the camera.
You would only be able to use a microSD if you would use an adaptor to transform that microSD into an SD

Comment: As also pointed out in Mike Sowsun's answer, though, that is *trivial* to work around (by using an adapter), *and* that applies equally to *all* microSD cards regardless of the amount of storage space they provide. Since the OP is specifically asking about microSD cards, I think it's safe to assume that the OP knows an adapter will be required to physically mount the card in the camera's slot, with makes that a peripheral note that should not be central to the answer the way it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Came to confirm that the Micro SD card 256 GB can be used through the adapter to the SD card with the Canon 5D Mark iii camera and can be formatted within the camera. Tested the shooting and brought it to the PC, okay, both raw and jpg.